# Multiplication price and profit with 2 number percentage in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, percentage, calculated-field

I have a product table where I save the price and the amount of profit.

I want to display the amount of time displayed differently

for example :

price : 8.08

profit : 8

Presentable : **8.08 + (8.08 * 8 / 100) = 8.7264**

Now I want the answer to be two decimal places and rounded up.

And the answer should be as follows:

Presentable : **8.08 + (8.08 * 8 / 100) = 8.73**

Answer (score 2):

The "C" currency format specifier should do the trick for you.

```
Dim amount As Decimal = 123.456

System.Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))

' Prints : $123.46
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString

There is a also a Round method, where you can specify to how many decimal places you would like to round the number. So in your case of rounding to 2 decimal places you could make a call like:

```
System.Math.Round(amount, 2, System.MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: `amount.ToString("N2")`

Comment: @iAm.Hassan The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.